Ubuntu 24.04 does not always boot
As Ubuntu 24.04 uses the 6.8 kernel by default, my boot-up process is often getting stuck. After selecting Ubuntu from the GRUB menu, it frequently fails to boot, with this issue occurring 7 out of 10 times. This means I can only boot into Ubuntu without any problem 3 out of 10 times.
I then downgraded the kernel to 6.6.x LTS. With this, the boot issue is reduced, and now most of the time I can boot into Ubuntu, but 1 out of 10 times, the boot still gets stuck.
I am using a Lenovo IdeaPad 5 with a Ryzen 7 processor, model 81YM (IdeaPad 5 14ARE05 U). Also, I'm dual-booting.

Instead of using an older kernel. Try 6.9. it has been used in Ubuntu 24.04 successfully 6.6 is not used by any version of Ubuntu.

Could this be related to this issue? Have you tried to simply wait for it to boot for up to 10 minutes?
Also, try to remove "quiet splash" from the kernel booting parameters in Grub to see the kernel's and systemd's log messages as it's booting - it would likely reveal what's going wrong.
